# How to design optimal and scalable unique page_view table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble coming up with the most optimal solution in designining a scalable page_view log sql model for postgresql

I designed a model with

```
create table views(
uuid,
chapterid,
createdAt
)
```

with uuid and chapterid being indexed as primarykey

```
create table daily_views(
day,
chapterid,
view_count
)
```

pre-aggregated table with day,chapterid being indexed as primarykey

```
create table monthly_views(
monthyear,
chaperid,
view_count)
```

pre-aggregated table with monthyear,chapterid being indexed as primarykey

and similar table with year,

but the views table will bloat with billions of rows, if the site's traffic reached such number, but i cannot delete it due to it tracking unique views for each chapter(for book) page.

should I continue with this schema or use timeseries database(i cannot use timescaledb for postgresql because it is not supported in rds(aws service))for this only and host my own ec2 instance of said database?

What I need from this data is to be able to calculate a trend, and to be able to count the total views for each book, related to the chapter....

Comment: Instead of tables you presumably plan to fill with triggers you should better use [materialized views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html).

Comment: from what i read, materialized views is not good for 'real time data', because Materialized views can go out of sync with the underlying data and need to be refreshed whenever that data changes. So every time i load new events into the events table, the program would need to run a refresh materiralized view [concurrently] to keep the view in-sync.

Comment: True, materialized views need to be refreshed. But you can do that, prior when you want to do your calculations.

Comment: hmm i see maybe i can refresh the materialized view every night and just not show that days page_views,e i will keep this in mind, in case i don't find better options i will go with your suggestion of using materialized view. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, that's the perfect use case of the [PipelineDB](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/introduction.html#overview) extension, as it allows real-time statistics with little overhead (but discards actual input data). For keeping the actual (raw) data, you should really consider the [Timescale](https://docs.timescale.com/introduction) extension to have reasonable write latency over time and growing data set. [Citus](http://docs.citusdata.com/en/latest/use_cases/timeseries.html) also has special support for time-series data.

You can also combine those two, although currently not supported first-class:

- https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/14
- https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipelinedb/issues/1876

If you really cannot make use of any of those, you have basically 2 options to decide where you'd want the additional performance penalty to apply:

1. performance penalty on writes: create a trigger that inserts/updates into a separate statistics table
2. performance penalty on reads: create a view or directly do an aggregation query

The option for materialized views also applies, but comes with an additional near-time requirement of todays' analytics applications.

Last but not least, don't forget that growing data sets by itself will become a serious issue on its own. So if you need something scalable in the long run, you **absolutely need** to account for that fact and even if starting without dynamic partitioning or other techniques, you should have a plan-B if things start to get slow.

Regarding the already foreseen issue of the data set size and always growing nature, you should also think about how precise the result have to be (not **SHOULD**, but **MUST** as in the business requirement). Please remember, that all of the bigger analytics providers will show you approximations, but very close to the real number.

Please have a read on different [counting options](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/) for this (e.g. the HLL extension from Citus is supported at RDS, at least).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, so the next question is that will hosting my own ec2 instance of timescaledb postgresql server be viable for a single person with limited time to offer. I'm so fixated on aws because I currently wish to not spend money, since I received a substantial amount of aws credit, but if push comes to shove, than I will have no choice but find alternative daas solution.

Comment: I don't know whether that actually works, but [scalegrid](https://scalegrid.io/postgresql/hosting-comparison.html) claims with their solution you can use any extension at AWS (I guess they are managing just plain EC2 instances). My experience tells me that without a lot of optimization for your use case you'll waste a lot of money in the long run (even if it is free for you in the beginning using your credits). You may also start with a plain RDS offering and ask the support guys to include support for at least pipelinedb and timescaledb extensions. Maybe they'll do before your credits run out

Comment: after contemplating your answer, I decided to delete the rows in delete tables every week, so as to prevent it from bloating to unreasonable heights as well as prevent people spamming the chapter page and only allow basically 4 views to register to a single page for a single user every month. This will allow rather accurate presentation of page views, and in the future when I can scale I will maybe host the postgres server in dbaas that allows timescaledb and piplelinedb extension. Thank you very much for you insight.